# How to mock a csv file

Tags: python, csv, mocking

I have a csv parser module that parses a very specific type of .csv file and extracts fields from it. Now to test this module I'm writing some unit tests. Traditionally, to test the module I would create a sample csv file of the same format but with limited entries and then pass in this file to the module and check the output. Obviously that's not very good because there's a dependency on the test file itself.

What is the right way to go about this? I've read about the **mock** module and how it can mock things. But I have no idea how I can mock a specific file.

Comment: A test file is just fine..

Comment: I mean, it's very unclear what bothers you about it?

Comment: A CSV file stands for 'comma-separated-values', meaning you can replace the CSV input with a simple string with comma separated values, such as: "hello,world,welcome"

Comment: `csv_file = Mock()`?

Comment: do you want to chek the existence of the file or the content too?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You did not supply any test data, so I hope my random examples translate well enough into your problem. In short: If you don't want to create temporary file objects during your tests (which is a reasonable constrain, imo), use `StringIO`. The `mock` module has a significant entry hurdle, so unless you want its fancier `mock`ing abilities, there is no need to use it.

```
from io import StringIO
from csv import reader  # this should import your custom parser instead

in_mem_csv = StringIO("""\
col1,col2,col3
1,3,foo
2,5,bar
-1,7,baz""")  # in python 2.7, put a 'u' before the test string
test_reader = reader(in_mem_csv, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
for line in test_reader:
    print(line)
    # whatever you need to test to make sure the csv reader works correctly
```

Output:

```
['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
['1', '3', 'foo']
['2', '5', 'bar']
['-1', '7', 'baz']
```

---

**Alternative string formatting**

I just personally prefer triple strings to represent files, normal strings might be better in your case. See this example for how to conveniently break lines and not change the string's value.

```
in_mem_csv = StringIO(
    "col1,col2,col3\n"
    "1,3,foo\n"
    "2,5,bar\n"
    "-1,7,baz\n"
)
```

Comment: Thanks. This fits my requirement perfectly. I'll try this out and see how it goes.

Comment: While this method works, the only downside is that in_mem_csv can't be indented properly and because my csv has 19 columns the whole thing is a mess, visually speaking.

Comment: @kronosjt I added an example with a normal string, and how it could be formatted. It can, of course, also be written up a lot more densely.

Comment: This works. The only thing I had to change was that instead of using with open and trying to read in a file-like object, I had to pass in the csv-like object directly to csv.reader(). In hindsight this is a better design because my csv parser should be able to parse any csv-like object.

Answer (score 4):

Below is an example of creating a mock CSV file using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
list = []
# It will create 100k records
for i in range(0,100000):

email = 'tester{i}@aeturnum.com'.replace("{i}",str(i))

phone = "0000000000"
phone = str(i) + phone[len(str(i)):] 

fname = "test" + str(i)
lname = "test" + str(i)

dob = "199{a}-{a}-0{a}".replace("{a}",str(len(str(i))))

list.append((fname, lname, email, phone, dob, str(i)))

columns = ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email Address', 'Phone Number','Date Of Birth','Current Loyalty Point Total']

df = pd.DataFrame(list, columns = columns)

print(df)

df.to_csv('user_data_100k.csv', index = False)
```