# How to mock a function taking in csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have a function that reads headers and rows from `csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")`, how can I create a mock `csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=","`) to pass to the function with headers and rows to read without creating new files in the app directory

Here is the function

```
def upload_loan_application(data):
    # skip headers row
    headers = next(data)
    for row in data:
       # read the row data here
```

and here is how it is called

```
with open(obj.file.path, "r") as csv_file:
     data = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")
     upload_loan_application(data)
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to mock?

Comment: I would use a StringIO object

Comment: @PaulH please share how that can be used!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830223/how-to-mock-a-csv-file)